# Is it possible to add custom email template with System.resetpassword()

Tags: email, email-template, reset-password

I have to send a custom email template with System.resetpassword() method. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can use [**`System.resetPasswordWithEmailTemplate(userId, sendUserEmail, emailTemplateName)`**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) in such scenarios. This method lets you specify the email template to be used while sending the email to the User.